# It is possible to reduce global sea level via filling empty lowlands with ocean water?

Tags: climate-change, sea-level

There are empty lowlands in Australia and Iran like Dasht-e Lut. If we fill these lands with ocean water then could we reduce the global sea level and save coastal cities like venice?

Comment: The math scales in [Did we ever record a reduction in sea level when the Panama canal was constructed?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/20475/did-we-ever-record-a-reduction-in-sea-level-when-the-panama-canal-was-constructe) may have some applicability

Comment: I doubt that would help subsidence of  costal cities built on silt and peat.  Although most  of these cites have stopped pumping fresh water out of underlaying aquafers . Maybe pump sea water into these aquifers to compensate for subsidence ?

Comment: [What fraction of dry land is below sea level?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/3018/6535)

Comment: Do you want to pump the water once, or continuously keep pumping?

Comment: Continuously keep pumping.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iranrud
https://waterse.ir/fill-iranian-desert-with-sea-water/

Comment: Thank you all for comments.

Answer (score 1):

Based on calculations of the effect of melting ice on sea level, we know that to effect a 1 mm change in global sea level requires around 360 km3 water. The largest lake by volume, [Lake Baikal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Baikal), contains just under 24,000 km3 of water. So if you created an equivalent lake you would lower sea level by 66 mm. At current rates of global sea level rise that would offset less than 20 years of melting ice and thermal expansion.